# C: Printing words from a file using fgetc

Tags: c, file, command-line, stdin, fgetc

I'm trying to write a simple main function that takes in a file through the command line, and prints all the words in the file.

However, I've followed several tutorials that just don't seem to work. Here's my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc < 2) return 1;
    char * filename = argv[1];
    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "r");

    if(file == NULL) {
      perror("Error opening file");
      return(1);
   }

   char c;
   while((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        if(c == ' ' || c == '\n')
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c", c);
        }
    }
    printf("Done.");
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

So far it has returned nothing, and doesn't show an error. The command line looks like this:

```
C:\Users\<USERNAME>\Desktop\C_C++>program.exe < file.txt

C:\Users\<USERNAME>\Desktop\C_C++>program.exe > file.txt

C:\Users\<USERNAME>\Desktop\C_C++>
```

It's using a windows command line. I didn't know whether or not I had to use `>` or `<` when passing in a file parameter, but I've also just used the file's name in place of `filename` in `FILE* file = fopen(filename, "r");` to just open it directly instead of passing the filename as a parameter, but nothing shows.

I have no idea what is going wrong.

Comment: redirection "arrow" follows direction of data: `program < file.txt` sends file.txt into program's stdin, `program > file.txt` sends program stdout to file.  Note that in your case that invocation has no stdout , only stderr (which I didn't see ?) because you didn't give it at least 2 arguments.  Once you `> file.txt` at least in unix shells you've told the shell to open and truncate for writing, and `file.txt` is now 0 bytes.  Then you output nothing to it so you might need to re-seed your `file.txt` at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fgetc()` returns `int`, not `char`. You need to declare

```
int c;
```

Otherwise, there's a possibility that the test for `EOF` will never succeed.

Your program expects the filename as a command-line argument, it doesn't read from standard input. So you have to give the filename as an argument, not use input redirection. The program is exiting immediately because `argc` is `1`.

```
program.exe file.txt
```

You should add an error message so you'll know this is the problem:

```
if (argc < 2) {
    printf("Usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Should only use `argv[0]` if `argv >= 1`, not just `argc < 2`.

Comment: Yes, the redirect symbols `<` and `>` cause standard input and standard output to be redirected to/from file.txt, instead of file.txt being passed as a command line argument. The program should work if these symbols are removed.

Comment: @chux In a hosted environment I think it's safe to assume `argv[0]` will always be set.

Comment: I think so to, yet consider poorly formed `exec()` calls.